# Number of Real Solutions to a logarithmic equation

Tags: functions, logarithms, exponential-function

"How many real solutions does the following equation have?"
$$\log_6(3x-26)-\log_6(x+2)=\log_6(-7+x)$$

I tried 2 methods and both gave me $x=6$; $x=2$ so I selected *Two Real Solutions, Both Positive* however the practice test is telling me the answer is *No Real Solutions*

Where am I going wrong and is there a quicker method to answering the question than solving the entire equation?

Comment: You forgot to check if the arguments to the logarithms are positive !

Comment: I don't know if there is a quicker method, because you didn't say what method you used. So this may or may not be quicker. You can transform the equation to $3x-26=(x+2)(x-7)$ which is a quadratic with roots $2,6$. After that you must check if the monomials $3x-6,x+2,x-7$ are positive for 2 and 6, as Yves pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

your equation can be simplified to
$$\log_6\left(\frac{3x-26}{x+2}\right)=\log_6(-7+x)$$ this can be simplified to
$$\frac{3x-26}{x+2}=-7+x$$ can you solve this?
it must be $$3x-26>0$$ and $$x+2>0$$ and $$-7+x>0$$
we get $$x=2$$ or $$x=6$$

Comment: yes this is right, you must make a Control and set These solution in the original equation

Comment: As others have pointed out already, because substituting these values makes the arguments of the logs negative, they cannot be solutions to the original equation.

Comment: and the last inequality $$-7+x>0$$ is not fulfilled

Comment: yes i know this

Comment: This is how I did it the first time. However I didn't plug the solutions back into the equation and I think that's where my error was. Thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be no real solutions.  Notice that substituting your answers back in gives log(negative number) on the right hand side of your equation.  Negative numbers are not included in the domain of logarithms.  Therefore, your answer is no real solution.

Comment: I see. So for an extra step I have to plug my solutions back into the equation, if it does not satisfy the logarithm's properties they are not real solutions?

Comment: Yes, that is correct